# Disable azurewebsites.net subdomain

Tags: azure, web

We have our company website hosted at Windows Azure Websites and set up an A-Record for our domain.

The problem is that one can also reach our site using the mangomint subdomain of http://azurewebsites.net (I don't want to post the full url here because Google shouldn't see this). This is bad in terms of SEO and duplicate content.

How can I disable the subdomain in favor of our main domain?

Comment: Have you added your hostname using a `CNAME` or an `A` record?

Comment: it is clear in the question that Daniel has set A-Record...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I don't think you can change the official azurewebsites.net DNS records, so you have only two solutions :

- Find a way to disable this subdomain in the Azure Websites configuration **EDIT: Not possible, from what astaykov said in the comments. thanks to him.**
- Make your website automatically redirect (HTTP 301, permanent redirect) the user when he lands on the subdomain.

Comment: [Google's web master pages](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066&topic=2371375) has some more workarounds.

Comment: Of course, but this is a Google specific solution. The asker wanted to "disable" his subdomain.

Comment: heavily rely on option 2, since disabling the Azure Websites domain is not possible.

Comment: Thanks! It's a pity that I can't disable it from the management portal. However, the solution with 301 redirects should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004077/azure-website-301-redirect-where-do-i-put-it