# Azure Website 301 Redirect - Where Do I Put It?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, azure, web-config

I want to direct some of my other domains to my primary domain which is hosted at a Windows Azure website.

*(For the sake of those that find working with CNAME's and DNS a little "foggy" (like I did) I'm going to layout the details.)*

I have the domain `www.myDomain.example` correctly resolving.

I now want to point `www.myOtherDomain.example to www.myDomain.example`

At my registrar I have created a CNAME to point
`www.myOtherDomain.example to myInternalAzureSite.azurewebsite.net`

and then successfully configured it in the in the Azure Website domain manager tool.

Now, when I enter `www.myOtherDomain.example` into a browser I get the proper web page at `www.myDomain.example`, however, the address in the browser is still `www.myOtherDomain.example` not `www.myDomain.example` as desired.

I understand the two most desirable ways to accomplish this are either:

1. Forward `myOtherDomain.example` (which costs $ at some registrars)
2. Do a 301 permanent redirect

If I have all that correct, I have found many suggestions of **HOW** to do the 301 redirect, however, I can't seem to figure out **WHERE** to actually put the redirect?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Windows Azure Websites run IIS. You can use URL rewriting to create rules to rewrite one URL to another.

Instructions:

1. Create a website in Windows Azure.
2. In the Scale section, select a web site mode of Shared or Standard and save changes.
3. In the Configure section, on the domain names group, add the old domain name (or names) and the new domain name and save changes.
4. In your domain registrar or DNS provider for the old domain and the new domain, change the DNS records to point to the new Windows Azure Website. Use a "CNAME (Alias)" record and point it to the website's domain on Windows Azure, like this: "mywebsite.azurewebsites.net."
5. Upload your new website's contents to Windows Azure.
6. In the root of the new website, create a file named `Web.config` with a contents like this:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url=".*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.old-domain.example$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.new-domain.example/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
   ```
7. Verify that any request to `http://www.old-domain.example/path?query` will receive a "301 Moved Permanently" response with a Location header for `http://www.new-domain.example/path?query`.

For documentation refer to [Using the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module).

For examples refer to [Redirect to new domain after rebranding with IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://itmeze.com/2011/04/07/redirect-to-new-domain-after-rebranding-with-iis-url-rewrite-module) and [IIS URL Rewrite – Redirect multiple domain names to one](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/30/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Fernando, in my case myOtherDomain.com never had a site, it's just the .net, .org, misspellings.com etc of the primary site.

Comment: No problem, I adjusted my answer for this situation. In this case you create a website for this other domain and put the redirect rules in this website, redirecting to the target domain.

Comment: Fernando, sorry for my ignorance, but I'm just about there. Can (or should) the website that the domain to be redirected be the target site? For example, myOldDomain.com points to newDomain.com and does the perm redirect there in the root web.config of newDomain.com?

Comment: It could be either way, but it might be simpler to have the web.config in the target website. I've updated my answer with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: That's great Fernando! Thank you for going into the detail, this post will help many people. It's so basic once you see the whole solution from DNS to web.config, but until you have done it, it's a little convoluted. When you search for 301 redirect, all that comes back is all the help directly with the rewrite rules. This helps, Thanks!

Comment: Since the pattern is a regex, won't the dot match any character? I believe it needs to be escaped.

Comment: Just a question, what if I wanted something like this .. https://pinoydev.com/old-url-path to https://pinoydev.com/new-url-path how do I edit your web.config code?

Answer (score 12):

There's no need to upload web.config file as there is one that you can access through the Azure interface.

Open the settings pane for your App Service and click App Service Editor (Preview) in the Development Tools section towards the bottom of the left hand menu.

Click Go to open the Editor in a new tab. You will see the web.config file on the left. Click it to edit in the main pane.

One word of warning - this editor *autosaves as you type*! I'm sure we'd all do this anyway but I'd recommend preparing your code in an editor and pasting it in.

I was able to add a  section without having to manually restart the App Service.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do the redirect by placing this code in your `web.config` file under the `configuration` node:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="oldpage1.php">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://example.com/newpage1" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="oldpage2.php">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://example.com/newpage2" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me, it's showing a HTTP 404 for my old page that no longer exist. Any idea of what might be?

Comment: Are you sure you included the right location in the 'path' property of the location tag?

Comment: i have made a mistake, i was trying to use this code to redirect all request of a specific directory not a single file. I solved my problem changing the web.config with a  httRedirect tag in system.webserver.

Answer (score -4):

I've taken a simpler approach and just added the extra required domains to the Azure App Service via the Custom Domains menu - per the screenshot below. No need to touch the main websites web.config file at all. No need for any explicit 301 redirect.  In Custom Domains page, just assign the domains, add the SSL bindings by uploading your HTTPS certificates - hit the site! [image]

Comment: But now you weaken your SEO and have to create certificates for all the domains. Seems like more work.

Comment: This will not redirect to new domain if you browse with old domain.