# Redirect .azurewebsites.net to domain for MVC.Core

Tags: azure, redirect, asp.net-core-mvc

How to redirect all traffic from xxx.azurewebsites.net to xxx.com?

This question is asked and answered many more but all the solutions are using `Web.Config` rewrite rule.
[StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004077/azure-website-301-redirect-where-do-i-put-it)

I have a MVC Core application and I don't have, nor want to create, a `Web.Config`.

Is there any solution for MVC Core that doesn't include `Web.Config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have the web.config in [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/08/how-to-access-kudu-scm-for-an-azure-app-service-environment-ase/), you could go to `xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net` and click **Debug console>site>wwwroot>web.config** to get your web.config and modify it.

Also, you could Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: So I download this web.config, add the rewrite rule and include it at the /wwwroot/ folder of my project?

Comment: You do not need to download, you could modify it directly in KUDU.

Comment: Ok, but if I ever 'Delete files before publishing' it will erase that and lose this setting... or not?

Comment: Yes. You could not delete and when you publish it will not be override.